# How to transfer file permissions from one folder to another?

Tags: filesystem, permissions, files, backup, chmod

I did `cp -r` on a folder *(copy)*, then removed the original.  I have a backup with most of the files.  How do I restore the permissions of the files & folders on the copy using the backup?

*It would be very tedious to go in and do `chmod XXX filename` every single item in there.*

Comment: [Related.](http://serverfault.com/questions/58277/copy-permissions-to-identical-tree-on-linux-unix)

Comment: So next time, use `rsync -a` or `cp -a`, whichever's available, to have the permissions preserved in the first place ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` to query the mode on your backup file, and `chmod` to update your working files. Do this in a loop, with a little string manipulation, and you have a solution. Something like this should work to copy the permissions:

```
# path to the top level of the backup
backup_dir=/path/to/backup/dir

# path to the directory of files that you want to restore
# permissions on.
dir=/path/to/working/dir

find "$backup_dir" |
while read backup_file
do
    new_file="$dir${backup_file#$backup_dir}"
    chmod --reference="$backup_file" "$new_file"
done
```

Note that this won't work well if your filenames contain the newline character (but thats's pretty rare). Also, it's untested, so you may want to do a "dry-run" by changing 'chmod' to 'echo chmod', so it just prints what it would do.

Comment: GNU chmod has a --reference option which would simplify that bit. `chmod --reference="$backup_file" "$new_file"`.

Comment: @geirha: nice! updated.

Answer (score 0):

What backup system are you using?  If it is Ubuntu backup, you can restore the original using nautilus.  Right-click in the parent folder and choose "Restore missing files" from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

use `cp -a` or more generally `cp --preserve=all`

from the man page

```
       --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
              preserve  the  specified  attributes   (default:   mode,owner‐
              ship,timestamps),  if possible additional attributes: context,
              links, xattr, all
```

`chmod` also has a recursive (`-R`) option.

Comment: This will copy files while retaining their ownership, permissions, and other attributes. But this question is about how to copy *just the attributes* (or at least the permissions); that is, how to apply them to files that have already been copied with some method that didn't preserve them in the destination.